Hardware driver compiling from Vitis for USRP devices of Ettus
I am new at sdr world. I am willing to work on sdr from ettus (E320) I know about uhd and its usage from gnuradio. However I dont want to use any oot application on my computer and I am not sure about that we can use the C api on embedded os on zynq (petalinux etc.). Does anyone know about how to run the api without using the computer?

The E320 is a computer. So, you can write any UHD API targetting program, compile it for and run it on the E320.

C api on embedded os on zynq (petalinux etc.

The E320 runs its own Linux, which is not a Petalinux. And the native ("embedded" or not) API of UHD is C++ – the C wrapper is a lower-performance one in case you need to wrap the C++ code in a different programming language (e.g. you want to develop a Lua scripting language binding).
However, you mention Vitis in your question title, that is wholly unrelated.
You probably want to read a few of the application notes on kb.ettus.com ; we can't help you with a question as blurry and unbounded in scope as this!
As a rule of thumb: you don't want to work on the device's FPGA itself unless you have a compelling technical reason to do so. Hardware is much harder than software to develop and most importantly, to debug. You will need a software model that does exactly the same as you want your hardware to do anyways – in digital hardware (i.e., in your case, FPGA) design, you always verify what your hardware does against a reference software.
